# Which component of angular momentum will be constant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

A particle moving in a potential $$V=x^2 +y^2 +\frac{z^2}{2}$$ Which of these components of the angular momentum,viz $L_x ,L_y$  and  $L_z$ is constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only $L_z$ because the symmetries of the spherical potential (the whole rotation group $SO(3)$) is broken by the $1/2$ factor to rotations around the $z$ axis ($SO(2)$). Because $L_z$ is the charge that generates these rotations, it will be conserved by Noether's theorem.